# How to extract text from PDF to highlight and on touch show definition of word

Tags: android, text, highlight, ontouchlistener, mupdf

Is there a way to extract text from pdf and store in variable to highlight and on ontouch show the meaning of the text. I am using MUPDF Library in android. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to know all the functionality and code from here?

Comment: @freak  I loaded the pdf and implemented settings like brightness and book mark now i need to highlight some of the text and ontouch of the text have to show the definition....

Comment: And the heading of your question is `How to extract text from PDF in Android` ...? change the title of your question and write it according to your need